# convert into a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way to convert this:

```
Tue Aug 28 13:59:01 +0000 2012
```

Into a DateTime Object?

I need to diff the above value with a DateTime Object.

Comment: Um I guess I am confused because that's not a Unix timestamp...do I have to parse that date out into a Unix Timestamp first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it into the DateTime constructor...

```
$date = new DateTime('Tue Aug 28 13:59:01 +0000 2012');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime($yourDate);
```

this will covert to standard DateTime object

check php manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) . Example 2 will make it clear.